# R heatmap.2 skip column or row labels

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

I am trying to plot a matrix of values over a range using heatmap.2. The columns are the range (for example, 0 to 100). There are too many column labels to display clearly. Is there a way to display every Nth one (0, 10, 20, etc)? I want all the values to be displayed, but I just don't want them all to be labeled.

Comment: Can you give an example of your dataframe/dataset please?

Comment: Do you require the dendrogram?

Comment: No dendogram required, since there is no clustering. I am really just visualizing measurements over a time period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inserting the labels into a vector of NAs and passing it to the `labCol` argument worked for me.

```
library(gplots)
m <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol=100)

labvec <- c(rep(NA, 100))
labvec[c(1,20,40,60,80,100)] <- c(1,20,40,60,80,100)
heatmap.2(m, trace="none", Rowv = T, Colv = F, labCol = labvec, srtCol = 0)
```

[image: Heatmap reduced column labels]
The `srt` argument can also be used to turn the labels horizontal.